# main:ZooKeeperServerMain@54 - Invalid arguments, exiting abnormally

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am new to using Zookeeper and trying to learn it using [Zookeeper](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028901.do) book. Now to start the server in standalone mode it is given in book as to use the command `bin/zkServer.sh start`.

I am using Windows so I ran the command as `bin/zkServer.cmd start` and now I get a strange error as :

```
D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6>bin\zkServer.cmd start

D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6>java "-Dzookeeper.log.dir=D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin\.." "-Dzookeeper.root.logger=INFO,CONSOLE" -cp "D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin\..\build\classes;D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin\..\b
ild\lib\*;D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin\..\*;D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin\..\lib\*;D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin\..\conf" org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain "D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin\..\conf
zoo.cfg" start
2014-04-04 21:00:06,573 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2014-04-04 21:00:06,576 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2014-04-04 21:00:06,576 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2014-04-04 21:00:06,577 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@113] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2014-04-04 21:00:06,626 [myid:] - ERROR [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@54] - Invalid arguments, exiting abnormally
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6\bin\..\conf\zoo.cfg"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerConfig.parse(ServerConfig.java:60)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:83)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:52)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:78)
2014-04-04 21:00:06,629 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@55] - Usage: ZooKeeperServerMain configfile | port datadir [ticktime] [maxcnxns]
Usage: ZooKeeperServerMain configfile | port datadir [ticktime] [maxcnxns]

D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6>endlocal
```

Can someone please help me in understanding why I am getting this error? The commands has changed from what are mentioned in this [Zookeeper](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028901.do) book?

After going through this SO post [zookeeper not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765015/zookeeper-not-starting) I am able to make the zookeeper up by omitting the input `start` for the command. Is it the correct way of starting a server in standalone mode?

Here is my configuration file for zookeeper:

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just 
# example sakes.
#dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
dataDir=D:\dataDir
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the 
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

Answer (score 35):

There may be some changes in the Zookeeper 3.4.6.
For this version start the server as shown below:

bin\zkServer.cmd

E.g.

```
D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6>bin\zkServer.cmd
```

Note, you don't need to pass the command line arg "start"

Comment: Thanks Nipun, also I am trying to stop the server using `bin\zkServer.cmd stop` even then also I am getting same error. Can you please tell me how to stop the server? is it using `Ctrl+C` or is there any other command t use?

Comment: I think now it is only way or kill the process from task manager. With Zookeeper 3.4.5 all these start/stop commands should work. Another way is to use admin commands. Basically you need to connect to Zookeeper server and issue the "kill" commands. You may use a telnet client for the same.

Answer (score 1):

There may be two possibilities

1. changes in the Zookeeper 3.4.6. For this version start the server as shown below:

bin\zkServer.cmd

`D:\zoo\zookeeper-3.4.6>bin\zkServer.cmd`

2. There may be white spaces in the MyID file
   eg`"1 "[Image link before edit of myid][1]`
   change it to

   "1" [Image link after edit of myid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUAev.png)